# Unable to cast to object

Tags: c#, list, object, casting, enumerator

I had a code:

```
var result = BOBase.Search(Mapper.SourceBrowserType, searchCriteria);
var list = new List<IBO>(result.OfType<IBO>());
```

But I need to be able to add many elements in a list. I tried:

```
var list = new List<IBO>();
var result = BOBase.Search(Mapper.SourceBrowserType, searchCriteria);
list.Add((IBO)result.OfType<IBO>());
```

Which results in an error:

```
Unable to cast object of type '<OfTypeIterator>d__95`1[BO.IBO]' to type 'BO.IBO'.
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: `OfType` will return a collection: `IEnumerable<TResult>`. The problem is that you try to cast this entire collection to a single element. and it seems that you want only a single element, or do you want all elements of this type?

Comment: Probably you are looking for [`List.AddRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-7.0)

Comment: `var list = new List<IBO>(result.OfType<IBO>());` should add many elements to the list.

Comment: "But I need to be able to add many elements in a list" Which `new List<IBO>(...)` **does**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OfType` will return a collection: IEnumerable. The problem is that you try to cast this entire collection to a single element. Hence the error message.

The cast is already performed by the `OfType` call. You would need a different adding method. It is called [AddRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-8.0).

> Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the List.

```
list.AddRange(result.OfType<IBO>());
```

Answer (score 1):

The second snippet should use [`AddRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-7.0) without extra casting to `IBO`:

> Adds the elements of the specified collection to the end of the `List<T>`.

```cs
var list = new List<IBO>();
var result = BOBase.Search(Mapper.SourceBrowserType, searchCriteria);
list.AddRange(result.OfType<IBO>());
```

Note that both snippets will doe the same. If you have only one source collection then just use the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an extra `Add***`-call, just use the constructor that expects an `IEnumerable<IBO>`:

```
var list = new List<IBO>(result.OfType<IBO>());
```

> But I need to be able to add many elements in a list.

In fact the above does exactly that: it adds all the elements of the specified type into your newly created list.

Alternativly use this:

```
var list = result.OfType<IBO>().ToList();
```